# How subscribe in redux called many times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

https://redux.js.org/basics/store#dispatching-actions

In this the `unsubscribe` function is called once. But the console gets printed too many times. How this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in code snippet

`// Note that subscribe() returns a function for unregistering the listener`

meaning subscribing to store returns just a function, but in subscription you are printing the store each time it is updated/changes, hence you are seeing 7 console statements from 1. first console.log and rest 6 statements before calling the unsubscribe function.

And as per your question, how subscribe is called many times =>
Its not the subscribe getting called,

`const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))`

On this line what we have done is passed a callback function, which gets executed each time store is changes, and from the below lines we are updating it from `dispatch`, you can see the console.logs from the callback function.

Comment: So can we use that subscribe() before the cosonle.log() lines?

Comment: yes, you can, subscribe to updates anytime after create a store.